# Tensorflow crashes RStudio

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, rstudio

I'm new with Deep learning plataforms and want to learn some in R, that the language I already work. I bought the book "Deep Learning with R" by François Chollet and am doing the step-by-step start.

I'm trying to install Keras and Tensorflow in Rstudio, following the instruction in the book. Those are lines that it recomends to install Keras in a r-reticulate enviroment:

```
install.packages("keras")
library(reticulate)
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = install_python())
library(keras)
install_keras(envname = "r-reticulate")
```

Everything looks to be good, by when i call

```
tensorflow::tf_config()
```

it returns an error and crashs Rstudio:

```
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.181883:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:86] read out of range
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.182056:ERROR elf_image_reader.cc:558] missing nul-terminator
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.182266:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.187120:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.187265:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.187405:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.187542:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.187687:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.189114:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.189250:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.191947:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.192085:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.192210:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.192340:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.192476:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.192619:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.192755:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.192957:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.193332:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.193497:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.193649:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.193781:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.193914:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.194157:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.194284:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.194420:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.195135:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.195273:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.195403:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.195527:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.195646:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.195770:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.195899:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.196031:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.196151:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.196277:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.196399:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.196525:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.196652:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.196780:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[31370:31370:20240322,021852.196904:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
```

I have already try alternative solution, like install Tensorflow from Rstudio with `install.packages("tensorflow")` and `library(tensorflow)`, as well as install as to install Python from the bash, as was recomended by Rstudio prompt. Nothing worked.

Could some one please help?

Comment: The same error message was reported for editors (RStudio, VSCode) on Linux and appears to be related to the graphics card driver; for suggestions see, e.g. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7310